# How to create hibernate composite key using annotations

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations, queryover

I am trying to use `hibernate annotations` to insert data to a `MySQL database` table which doesn't have a primary key defined.

However the fact is 2 fields of that table together are unique in the table.how can i achieve the same using hibernate annotation?.

here is my code..

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "RolesMenuItems")
    public class RolesMenuItems {

       @Column(name = "RoleID")
       private String roleID;

       @Column(name = "MenuItemID")
       private String menuItemID;
  /*setter getter methods */
 }
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `@Embeddeble` and `@EmbeddedId` to create a composite key and map it with your Entity. For example:

```
@Embeddable
public class RolesMenu {
    @Column(name = "RoleID")
    private String roleID;

    @Column(name = "MenuItemID")
    private String menuItemID;

    //getter, setter methods
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "RolesMenuItems")
 public class RolesMenuItems {

     @EmbeddedId
     private RolesMenu roleMenu;

  /*setter getter methods */
 }
```

Then use `RolesMenuItems` in your Java code to persist entities in usual way.

Reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e535

**Edit:** 
To persist the entity:

```
RolesMenu roleMenu = new RolesMenu();
roleMenu.setRoleID(...);
roleMenu.setMenuItemID(...);

RolesMenuItems roleItem = new RolesMenuItems();
roleItem.setRoleMenu( roleMenu );

em.persist(roleItem);
```

Comment: OK thank you..but how can i insert values for roleID and  menuItemID..can you please tell me??

Comment: Updated the answer. Pl have a look.

Comment: have any getter setter methods in RolesMenu class??

Comment: how can i specifies column names for roleID,menuItemID?

Comment: Can we generate the composite key using generation strategies? I mean `roleID` and `menuItemID` as Auto increment. I guess yes, we can do it.