# i try to create composite primary key with @UniqueConstraint

Tags: hibernate, composite-key, composite-primary-key

i try to create composite primary key in table from 2 foreign key using hibernate.but i do not now the way how to set it.
@UniqueConstraint can some body help me..

Comment: Have you tried something, some tutorial? Can you post your entity class where you want to have composite PK? You should not need `@UniqueConstraint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need @UniqueConstraint if you declare that composite key as your @EmbeddedId see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936340/to-create-hibernate-composite-key-using-annotations) for the example.

you only need a class to become it's composite id:

```
@Embeddable
public class SomeCompositeClass {
    @Column(name = "SOME_ID_1")
    private String someId1;

    @Column(name = "SOME_ID_2")
    private String someId2;

    //getter, setter methods
}
```

then use it inside your entity to became its `@EmbeddedId` :

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "YOUR_MAIN_TABLE")
 public class YourMainTable {

     @EmbeddedId
     private SomeCompositeClass myCompositeId ;

  /*setter getter methods */
 }
```