# Exception with @JoinTable and shared key in many-to-many relathionship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, join

I have a table what represent a many to many relationship.

```
+----------+           +------------+           +----------+
|   User   |           | UserGroups |           |  Group   |
+----------+           +------------+           +----------+
| id   (PK)|---(1,N)---| user_id    |---(N,1)---| id   (PK)|
| year (PK)|           | year       |           | year (PK)|
| name     |           | group_id   |           | name     |
+----------+           +------------+           +----------+
```

In Java, I have only the entity User and Group, and I don't like to have UserGroups in Java model because It didn't provide more information that the relationship. My class User is like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
  @EmbeddedId
  private UserPK id;
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "UserGroups",
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
                             @JoinColumn(name = "year", referencedColumnName="year") },
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                                    @JoinColumn(name = "year", referencedColumnName = "year") })
  private List<Group> groups;
}
```

When I try to run the application I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException:Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.testapp.model.entities.User.groups column: year
```

I don't want to have UserGroups in my Java model.
I don't want to create another year column in UserGroups table.
**How I can do this relation in Java?**

Comment: This is supposed to be possible, see [Many-to-many with shared composite key attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html#example-mappings-composite-key-manytomany).

Answer (score 0):

I am not at expert in this topic, at all. But I do know the following:

The join table can relate/connect `User` and `Group` entities through their IDs only because they are `unique`. At the moment you are adding the field `year` int he equation, you are *ignoring* that requirement.

Conclusion: You have to remove year from the join table.

Option: Making unique as couple "user_id & year" for User table and "group_id & year" for Group table might work. I doubt that though.

Comment: Sorry but It's not the solution. Year is part of the primary key in User and Group. In my model is not the same User(id=1, year=2013) than User(id=1, year=2014), so I couldn't remove the year column. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hmm! Very interesting DB design I have to say... Anyhow, have you tried to generate a custom PK by using/mixing `user_id` and `year`? Hibernate offers such possibility.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936340/to-create-hibernate-composite-key-using-annotations and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation.

Comment: If i don't use JoinTable annotation and I use EmbeddedId, Hibernate try to search "user_year" in UserGroups, so I need to specify what column's name is "year" with JoinTable annotation, So I have again the origin problem for use JoinTable annotation.

Comment: Give it a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation

Comment: That is not my case. I don't have the annotations in getters and my many-to-many table have two keys per table, not one per table.